# Image cannot be loaded - Javafx

Tags: image, javafx, load

I`m trying to load image with code:

```
Image image = new Image(AddOrderController.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/icons/ok_icon.png"));
```

And I receive exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null
```

The tree of my project is simple:

[image: tree of project]

When I'm adding `ok_icon.png` to package controller everything is ok and icon works, but in `resources/icons` the icon can't be loaded. Can anyone help me how to remake the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `src/test/resources` as a source folder, the contents of `resources` will be deployed as part of the application, to the root of the classpath. That means that `icons` is in the root of the classpath.

You can verify this by checking the contents of the output folder, which I'm guessing is `target/classes`, using the system file browser (Finder on a Mac, or Windows explorer, or whatever it is called these days). You can verify the output folder in Eclipse by choosing "Project" from the menu, then "Properties", select "Java Build Path", select the "Source" tab, and see what is specified as the "Default output folder".

If the path you supply to `getResourceAsStream` begins with a leading `/`, then the path will be interpreted relative to the classpath. So

```
Image image = new Image(AddOrderController.class.getResourceAsStream("/icons/ok_icon.png"));
```

should work.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you have to go one directory up first:

```
Image image = new Image(AddOrderController.class.getResourceAsStream("../resources/icons/ok_icon.png"));
```

if that doesn't work neither, check if the two source folders (src) are really the same or if they have a different parent folder

Comment: It doesn`t work. I also checked locations of folders.

Comment: Never use `..` in resource paths. That is not a valid resource name. (It will work, if the path is correct, when your resources are on the file system, but will fail when you bundle the application in a jar file.)